# failed to build tool version android

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I tried to open an old project of mine in a freshly installed android studio (today), It gave me this error :

```
failed to find build tools revision 23.0.0 rc2
install build tools 23.0.0 rc2 and sync project
```

I looked for it in the internet and I tried to add this in the gradle file :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
}
```

And it gave me another error:

```
gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
possible causes:
the project may be using a version of gradle that does not contain the method.
gradle settings.
the build file may be missing a gradle plugin.
apply gradle plugin.
```

this is my gradle file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
}
```

Comment: I actually have mistaken it for another gradle file, instead of changing the project's build.gradle , i was writing in the libraries build.gradle

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project > Open Module Settings > Properties Tab, then change :

```
Compile Sdk Verion to API 23: Android 6.0
Build Tools Version 23.0.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I checked the build tools version installed in my Android Studio and I have Android SDK Build-Tools rc3, Not rc2. 
I changed it in build.gradle (Module App) to
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"}
After that it works.
Check if you have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your top level `build.gradle` you have to remove the `android` block

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 22
   buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
}
```

Just use:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
       repositories {
          jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
       }
    }

    allprojects {
       repositories {
         jcenter()
       }
    }
```

You have to use the `android` block, in the `app/build.gradle` where you should define something like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion XX
    buildToolsVersion "XX.X.X"

    defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion XX
       targetSdkVersion XX
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    } 
    buildTypes {
      release {
         //......
      }
    }
}
dependencies {
  //......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

theres 2 gradle files

the one you have to modify is the one under this directory 
APPLICATION NAME / APP / BUILD.GRADLE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "PUT THE CODE YOU WANT HERE EX "23.0.0 r3""

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.app.appname"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.10.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

not the one which looks like these

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried everything and finally I had to do a simple change from this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"
}
```

to this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0" //DELETE rc2 AND SYNC PROJECT 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Android SDK Build-tools you have installed, you could check it via the SDK Manager, in my case I haven't the 23.0.0 rc2 installed but the 23.0.1, so you need to edit your `app/build.gradle`

for me it was then:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}
```